# Creating date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I need to convert this date:

`10.04.2011 19:00`

To a date variable that I can use in PHP.

Can someone help me with that? I tried this way:

```
$dateConverted = date("d.m.Y H:i",strtotime ($date));
```

But it returns `01.01.1970 00:00`

Comment: Odd issue. I just tested this using `echo date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime("10.04.2011 19:00"));` and got back `10.04.2011 19:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to the rescue!

It looks like your format is `d.m.Y H:i`.

So, this should work for you:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', '10.04.2011 19:00');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You should also take a look at [the formats that `strtotime` and `DateTime` operate on](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).  In particular, the reason that date didn't parse in `strtotime` is that it only expects dots as delimiters between Y, M and D if the year is only two digits.  That's an odd one, don't look at me, it's not my fault.